# Spark: What is the Use of Creating New Spark Sessions?

Tags: apache-spark

We can create new Spark sessions by using spark.newSession in spark-shell.  Now, my question is what is the use of new Spark session instances?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two most common uses cases are:

- Keeping sessions with minor differences in configuration.

  ```
  Welcome to
        ____              __
       / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
      _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
     /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0
        /_/

  Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_141)
  Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
  Type :help for more information.

  scala> spark.range(100).groupBy("id").count.rdd.getNumPartitions
  res0: Int = 200

  scala> 

  scala> val newSpark = spark.newSession
  newSpark: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@618a9cb7

  scala> newSpark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 99)

  scala> newSpark.range(100).groupBy("id").count.rdd.getNumPartitions
  res2: Int = 99

  scala> spark.range(100).groupBy("id").count.rdd.getNumPartitions  // No effect on initial session
  res3: Int = 200
  ```
- Separating temporary namespaces:

  ```
  Welcome to
        ____              __
       / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
      _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
     /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0
        /_/

  Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_141)
  Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
  Type :help for more information.

  scala> spark.range(1).createTempView("foo")

  scala> 

  scala> spark.catalog.tableExists("foo")
  res1: Boolean = true

  scala> 

  scala> val newSpark = spark.newSession
  newSpark: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@73418044

  scala> newSpark.catalog.tableExists("foo")
  res2: Boolean = false

  scala> newSpark.range(100).createTempView("foo")  // No exception

  scala> spark.table("foo").count // No effect on inital session
  res4: Long = 1
  ```

Comment: So, when would you use this though?